# FreeBSD 11, setting up a DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, freebsd, reverse-dns

i want to setup dns server on my system. I do the configs from freeBSD document, but I don't succeed.
I do these steps:

**1. ee /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1               my-server my-server.my.domain
192.168.x.x           my-server my-server.my.domain
```

**2. ee /etc/resolve.conf**

```
search my-server.my.domain
nameserver 192.168.x.x
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

**3.ee /etc/rc.conf**

```
local_unbound_enable="YES"
```

4.`drill -S my-server.my.domain@192.168.x.x`

5.`service local_unbound restart/onestart`

6.`drill -S  my-server.my.domain`

=>**Existence denied or verifiably insecure**

and in terminal:

```
#host my-server.my.domain
```

=>Host my-server.my.domain not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Please help me to figure out the mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Hi F.M, and welcome to Server Fault. Can you say something about what it is you're trying to achieve? Do you want to run a local resolver?

Comment: Why do you want to run a DNS server? This is something that in most cases can be easily outsourced.

Comment: Hi @ jornane  and @Tim. Thanks for your responses. I want to set up ldap. I searched and notice that I should have dns server and reverse dns.

Comment: @Tim : running a local resolver is almost the only solution to do DNSSEC validation correctly.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that's interesting. I just CloudFlare, which does it for me. I note that even AWS Route53 doesn't do DNSSEC.

Comment: The problem in DNSSEC-world is trust. Full trust often means you need to do more things yourself. See `unbound` and `dnssec-trigger` software for example. And I was specifically speaking about recursive resolvers, not authoritative ones (like CloudFlare or Amazon Route53).

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake, except perhaps you should not have added `nameserver 127.0.0.1` to `/etc/resolv.conf` as `local_unbound_setup` does this automatically.

You do not have a DNS record for `my-server.my.domain`. The `/etc/hosts` file allows local applications to resolve names to IP addresses, but is not part of the name server.

The applications `drill` and `host` talk directly to the name server (which effectively ignores `/etc/hosts`).

For example, if you `ping my-server.my.domain`, the default behaviour is to consult `/etc/hosts` first and consult the DNS server second.

Comment: Thanks for tour response. I omit `nameserver 127.0.0.1 from /etc/resolv.conf` but it doesn't work!

Comment: I think you misread my answer. Why do you expect `host my-server.my.domain` to work?